# Double quotes passing by VBA to Powershell string

Tags: vba, powershell

I am trying to create a string, and inside I need to user some double quotes, I try many ways to do this, but all give me a error, please, anyone can help me?

```vb
Public Sub Script2()
    Dim ScriptText As String
    ScriptText = "[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(""""Message Text"""",""""Title"""",1)"
    Call shell("PowerShell -noexit powershell.exe  -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command " & ScriptText, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

If I try this way I get:

```
Message : The term 'Message' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    No line:1 character:88
    + ... ypass -Command[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(Message Text,Ti ...
    +                                                           ~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Message:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: replace double-quotes inside the string with single-quotes :)

Comment: No line:1 character:41
+ [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show Message Text Title 1
+                                         ~~~~~~~
Token 'Message' unexpected in expression or instruction.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Have you tried to execute your command directly?

Comment: Directly is not working too, but I prefer passing into a string, because I can create a entire script to insert there.

Comment: I believe you should initially get a working powershell command line and only then try to convert it into a vb string.

Comment: BTW, to make this code work you'll need to load an assembly before. See details here https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-show-a-messagebox/

And what I'm curious more and more - why do you need an external MessageBox? VBA has its own...

Comment: in Powershell ISE, directly works like a charm, the problem is when passing the double quotes inside a string from vba/vbs to powershell, the double quotes is not passed, lost their values.

Comment: Even here -> [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
 the double quotes is not passed inside a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is a working code (it's VBS but there shouldn't be much troubles to use it in VBA)

```
ScriptText = """[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Message Text','Title',1)"""
createobject("wscript.shell").run "powershell.exe  -noexit -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command " & ScriptText
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ` for each " that you need? This way you'll get something like this:

```
ScriptText = "[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(`"`"Message Text`"`",`"`"Title`"`",1)"
```

`"` is normally reserved, and if you need to write it in a string, you need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two levels of parameter expansion (one by VBA and one by Powershell) so you need to double escape your quotes. The doubled double-quotes get it past VBA. The backtick will escape it for Powershell.

```
ScriptText = "[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(`""Message Text`"",`""Title`"",1)"
```